# Do Vyasa Mahabharata say that Pandu has pandu disease?

Tags: mahabharata, pandu

Consider the following excerpt regarding birth of [Pandu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pandu)

> "Soon after Satyavati, O chastiser of foes, summoned Vyasa, after
>   having secured the assent of her daughter-in-law. Vyasa came according
>   to his promise, and approached, as before, the second wife of his
>   brother. And Ambalika beholding the Rishi, became pale with fear And,
>   O Bharata, beholding her so afflicted and pale with fear, Vyasa
>   addressed her and said, 'Because thou hast been pale with fear at the
>   sight of my grim visage, therefore, thy child shall be pale in
>   complexion. O thou of handsome face, the name also thy child shall
>   bear will be Pandu (the pale).' 'Saying this, the illustrious and best
>   of Rishis came out of her chamber. And as he came out, he was met by
>   his mother who asked him about the would-be-child. T**he Rishi told her
>   that the child would be of pale complexion and known by the name of
>   Pandu**. Satyavati again begged of the Rishi another child, and the
>   Rishi told her in reply, 'So be it.' Ambalika, then, when her time
>   came, **brought forth a son of pale complexion**. Blazing with beauty the
>   child was endued with all auspicious marks. Indeed, it was this child
>   who afterwards became the father of those mighty archers, the
>   Pandavas.
>
> [[SECTION CVI, Sambhava Parva, Adi parva, The Mahabharata]](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m01/m01107.htm)

It didn't mention that he has any disease. But when i read the translated versions, there are statements saying that he has a disease named **pandu**. So, is there any statement from Vyasa Mahabharata saying that Pandu has pandu disease?

Comment: I don't remember any statement about pandu having any disease, I think the word pandu should be "one of pale complexion" only.